# Adjusting video volume via component.ts in angular 2+

Tags: angular, html, video-streaming

I have a video that I display in my html template as below:

```
<video #videoplayer controls (click)="playVideo($event)" style="width: 100%" (ended)="openModal(template)">
     <source src="{{ videoSource }}" type="video/mp4"> 
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

My component.ts file is as below:

```
export class Episodes1Component implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: any;
  videoSource = 'my video source.mp4';

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  pauseVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();
  }

  playVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.muted = true;
    this.isEnded = false;
  }
}
```

What I want to do is adjust the volume to 0.2. The code that I use in component.ts is `this.videoplayer.nativeElement.volume= 0.2;` but it doesn't adjust the volume.

I tried `this.videoplayer.nativeElement.muted= true;` and add `muted` control inside the `video` html tag but I had the same: The vide starts with 100% volume.

I was wondering what would be the best way to control the volume. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a plunker demo
[Demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/QnbEvBqmlMeehePB?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: Could you provide an MVCE in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?

Comment: Sure! Just edited the question. Click on demo link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. You only have a typo:

`<video #videoPlayer controls`

`#videoplayer` -> `#videoPlayer`

Comment: You're right. But I still have volume loaded as 100%. Is `this.videoplayer.nativeElement.volume = 0.1;` not the right code?

Comment: It's correct. Here it gets set correctly: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/i4jChUy9C7Fky6J6?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Comment: Are you sure it's working? Even though I changed the volume to 0, I still hear the volume of the vide 100%

Comment: If you check out the plunker in my previous comment it works  It sets the volume from 100%, to 10% after 3 seconds, and after a total of 6seconds to 0%.

Comment: Nothing is happening either after 3 seconds or 6 seconds on my end. The volume is still 100% during the video on the plunker example. But I found a way to deal with this: If I place  `this.videoplayer.nativeElement.volume = 0.1;` to `ngOnInit()`, it worked.

Comment: What browser are you testing it with?

Comment: Chrome. And look what I found: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/2lN8hckg9cg/rVev4yKxBgAJ
This just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes I can certainly confirm the missing bar.